# Identifying a Programming Language

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, programming-languages, decompiler

So I have a software program that for reasons that are beyond this post, I will not include but to put it simply, I'd like to "MOD" the original software. The program is launched from a Windows Application named `ViaNet.exe` with accompanying DLL files such as `ViaNetDll.dll`. The Application is given an argument such as `./Statup.cat`. There is also a WatchDog process that uses the argument `./App.cat` instead of the former.

I was able to locate a log file buried in my Windows/Temp folder for the ViaNet.exe Application. Looking at the log it identifies files such as:

```
./Utility/base32.atc:_Encode32  line 67
./Utilities.atc:MemFun_:Invoke  line 347
./Utilities.atc:_ForEachProperty  line 380
./Cluster/ClusterManager.atc:ClusterManager:GetClusterUpdates  line 1286
./Cluster/ClusterManager.atc:ClusterManager:StopSync  line 505
./Cluster/ClusterManager.atc:ConfigSynchronizer:Update  line 1824
```

Going to those file locations reveal files by those names, but not ending with `.atc` but instead `.cat`. The log also indicates some sort of Class, Method and Line # but `.cat` files are in binary form.

Searching the program folder for any files with the extension `.atc` reveals three -- What I can assume are uncompiled `.cat` files -- files. Low and behold, once opened it's obviously some sort of source code -- with copyright headers, lol.

```
global ConfigFolder, WriteConfigFile, App, ReadConfigFile, CreateAssocArray;

local mgrs = null;
local email = CreateAssocArray( null);

local publicConfig = ReadConfigFile( App.configPath + "\\publicConfig.dat" );

if ( publicConfig != null )
{
    mgrs = publicConfig.cluster.shared.clusterGroup[1].managers[1];

    local emailInfo = publicConfig.cluster.shared.emailServer;
    if (emailInfo != null)
    {
        if (emailInfo.serverName != "")
        {
            email.serverName = emailInfo.serverName;
            }
        if (emailInfo.serverEmailAddress != "")
        {
            email.serverEmailAddress = emailInfo.serverEmailAddress;
        }
        if (emailInfo.adminEmailAddress != null)
        {
            email.adminEmailAddress = emailInfo.adminEmailAddress;
        }
    }   
}

if (mgrs != null)
{
    WriteConfigFile( ConfigFolder + "ZoneInfo.dat", mgrs);
}

WriteConfigFile( ConfigFolder + "EmailInfo.dat", email);
```

So to end this as simply as possible, I'm trying to find out two things. #1 What Programming Language is this? and #2 Can the `.cat` be decompiled back to `.atc.` files? -- and vice versa. Looking at the log it would appear that the Application is decoding/decompiling the `.cat` files already to interpret them verses running them as bytecode/natively. Searching for `.atc` on Google results in AutoCAD. But looking at the results, shows it to be some sort of palette files, nothing source code related.

It would seem to me that if I can program in this unknown language, let alone, decompile the existing stuff, I might get lucky with modding the software. Thanks in advance for any help and I really really hope someone has an answer for me.

***EDIT***

So huge news people, I've made quite an interesting discovery. I downloaded a patch from the vendor, it contained a batch file that was executing `ViaNet.exe Execute [Patch Script].atc`. I quickly discovered that you can use `Execute` to run both `.atc` and `.cat` files equally, same as with no argument. Once knowing this I assumed that there must be various arguments you can try, well after a random stroke of luck, there is one. That being `Compile [Script].atc`. This argument will compile also any `.atc` file to `.cat`. I've compiled the above script for comparison: http://pastebin.com/rg2YM8Q9

So I guess the goal now is to determine if it's possible to decompile said script. So I took a step further and was successful at obtaining C++ pseudo code from the `ViaNet.exe` and `ViaNetDll.dll` binaries, this has shed tons of understanding on the proprietary language and it's API they use. From what I can tell each execution is decompiled first then ran thru the interpreter. They also have nicknamed their language ATCL, still no idea what it stands for. While searching the API, I found several debug methods with names like `ExecuteFile`, `ExecuteString`, `CompileFile`, `CompileString`, `InspectFunction` and finally `DumpObjCode`. With the `DumpObjCode` method I'm able to perform some sort of dump of script files. Dump file for above script: http://pastebin.com/PuCCVMPf

I hope someone can help me find a pattern with the progress I made. I'm trying my best to go over the pseudo code but I don't know C++, so I'm having a really hard time understanding the code. I've tried to seperate what I can identify as being the compile script subroutines but I'm not certain: http://pastebin.com/pwfFCDQa
If someone can give me an idea of what this code snippet is doing and if it looks like I'm on the right path, I'd appreciate it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: It might help if you use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [PeStudio](http://www.winitor.com/) to look at the strings contained within `ViaNet.exe` and possibly even `ViaNetDll.dll`. There's no guarantee you'll find anything useful, but some binaries might have strings that'll point you in the right direction - for example, a look at my running `TortoiseHgOverlayServer.exe` reveals a `PYTHONSCRIPT` string hiding inside.

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I'm finding strings such as `C:\hudson\jobs\Respin_R5_Windows_Release\workspace\main\fixed\Arcturus\ViaNetDll\Src\pbtrectl.cpp` and `C:\Txs\arcturus\Bin\ViaNet.exe`. It looks like the exe calls directly on a dll method `ViaNetStartup` but I can't find anything inside the dll.

Comment: `pbtrectl.cpp` Looks like you're dealing with C++. I have no idea what to make of the `global` and `local` keywords, though. [They're not standard C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). I don't believe the lowercase `null` is either; I've always seen that done as `NULL`. So either you're dealing with non-C++ code saved in cpp files, or you're dealing with C++ that has some very... interesting... setup (probably `typedef`s everywhere). You might want to use [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) and see if you can find any useful dependencies (C++ runtime library, maybe?)

Comment: This stuff is obviously a variety of proprietary scripting dialect specific to a vendor of your software (March Networks, I would assume). Therefore, the only reasonable approach will be to try and nag their customer service in regards to possibly available documentation.

Comment: From what I can tell, `global` would be similar to something like `include` or `import`. `local` is some sort of var declaration. I was thinking something similar to `LUA` language with the use of `local` but `LUA` does not use Curly Brackets. My next guess was `Perl` but the `Perl` interpreter does not like this code snippet. The name after the keyword `global` are existing `.cat` files. I'm pretty sure this is some sort of obfuscated interpreted source code but the exact language is unknown to me. Google searches for both Arcturus, Respin R5, Vianet and Txs return nothing.

Comment: @oajad, Just out of curiosity what makes you assume March Networks?

Comment: @ChioriGreene It's not valid C++, C, C#, Perl, PHP, or Java. So oakad's idea of some proprietary scripting dialect seems reasonable enough.

Comment: I'm coming to that idea that it's some sort of proprietary language too. The only last thing I'm wondering is can the `.cat` files be decompiled back to `.atc`. I don't care so much for the main ViaNet.exe but if I can reverse engineer the actual program files then I might be in business.

Comment: I have found this http://translate.google.pl/translate?hl=pl&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.verydemo.com%2Fdemo_c131_i79132.html and it seems to be some kind of Android things. I have found some game searching for "Arcturus android": http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2187637 ps. I don’t know how accurate this is.